# HTML Tags for collapsible dropdown

Tags: html

The output is :

Test1(Collapsable Dropdown)
T1
T2
T3
Test2(Collapsable Dropdown)
B1
B2
B3
Test3(Collapsable Dropdown)
C1
C2

Desired Output:

```
       Test1(Collapsable Dropdown)
           T1
           T2
           T3
      
       Demo1(Collapsable Dropdown)
           Test2(Collapsable Dropdown)
               B1
               B2
               B3
           Test3(Collapsable Dropdown)
               C1
               C2
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it is to import JQuery. This is the code sample coded according to your requirements. Check if everything matches out. You can use class/id and CSS to change the way it looks. Hope this solves your question.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div data-role="page" id="pageone">
  <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h1>Test 1</h1>
      <p>T1</p>
      <p>T1</p>
      <p>T3</p>
    </div>
    <div data-role="collapsible">
      <h1>Demo 1</h1>
          <div data-role="collapsible">
              <h1>Test 2</h1>
              <p>B1</p>
              <p>B2</p>
              <p>B3</p>
          </div>
         <div data-role="collapsible">
              <h1>Test 3</h1>
              <p>C1</p>
              <p>C2</p>
          </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```